# "Эмпирический путь познания мира как единственно верный способ", - способ самодостаточен? не требует управляемого слова?

Tags: синтаксис, управление

> Ещё в юности он занимался рисованием, поэтому начал пописывать в стол
>   дилетантские статьи-компиляции по истории искусств, потом уже и
>   страшно наивно «О любви», чуть позже — незатейливые путевые очерки. И,
>   будучи ярым атеистом и приверженцем конституционной монархии (он
>   ужасно интересовался и политикой), этот самый Мари-Анри, увлёкшись
>   философией, вдруг **открыл для себя эмпирический путь познания мира
>   как единственно верный способ**. Мир — с позиции опыта.

Если непременно требуется правка, подскажите, пожалуйста, недостающее слово. Синонимы к "познанию" (и даже к познанию мира) меня мало утешили.

Главное: можно ли не править?

Comment: А просто убрать "способ"?

Comment: Гениально. Попробую предложить автору. ))) А как есть категорически нельзя?

Comment: Думаю, что нет. Требует управляемого слова. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

...вдруг открыл для себя эмпирический путь познания мира **в качестве единственно верного.** Мир — с позиции опыта.

Или:

...вдруг открыл для себя эмпирический путь познания мира, **посчитав его единственно верным.** Мир — с позиции опыта.